# Dynamic XML file path for crystal report using vb.net and MySQL

Tags: mysql, xml, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have developed vb.net app with MySQL and I am using crystal reports that are generated using data from XML files.

```vb
Using conn As New MySqlConnection(constr)
    Try
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim query_invoice_details As String = "SELECT cust_id,cust_name,cust_contact,cust_email,cust_address,IF(cust_type = 1,'Individual','Company')  'Customer Type',cust_comp_name FROM tbl_customers WHERE cust_status = 1;"
        conn.Open()
        da.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand(query_invoice_details, conn)
        da.Fill(ds)
        ds.WriteXml(CurDir() & "/CustomerReportDetails.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
        crCustomerReport1.Refresh()
    Finally
        If conn IsNot Nothing Then conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Using
```

Everything is working fine development stage but when the project is published, (installer created and installed), it cannot find the CurDir() to load the report from because, when I use DataExpert to design Crystal Reports, I have to physically select the file (which translates to "`E:\_netProjects\Invoices\Invoices\bin\Debug\CustomerReportDetails.xml`").

Is there any other way to solve this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you want the file to be when it's deployed?

Comment: I was just wondering if the location can be dynamic? because the same application will be installed in tens of PC's and hard coding the location may be kind of cumbersome. I actually worked on `Public RootPath As String = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory)` and then storing in some folder in root path, but just wondering if some PC doesn't allow creating folders/files in root DIR

Comment: Yes, you may want to use `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()` which creates a temp directory on your PC. This is useful if you need to work with the file system without the end-user needing to access the file in its path.

Comment: Thanks Verdoli for response, I have created crystal reports as given in this  video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRxTmSLFkPc . i.e., 1. Write the query result to XML File. 2. Select the XML file as source in crystal report Data Expert. So if i make some temp path, then i won't be able to select the datasource for crystal reports.